# Writing NULL char to file in C

Tags: c, string, file, hex, nul

I am attempting to write an array of char to a BMP file in C. The problem with this is that whilst 0x00 values are required for the file, it seems C interprets this as the end of string when writing to the file i.e. as a NULL char. Is there any way I can override this and have C rely purely on what I say is the number of char I wish to pass?

Code for writing the header to file (this function is executed in main);

```
void writeFile(void){
    unsigned char bmp1[54] = {
    0x42, 0x4D, 0x36, 0x00, 
    0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 
    0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x0C, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x00, 0x00
    };

    FILE *picFile = fopen("pic.bmp","w");
    fprintf(picFile, bmp1, 54);
    fclose(picFile);
}
```

Comment: Please note: `NULL` == `(char*)0`(a pointer) This is not 0x00 (a byte)

Comment: To cut it short: There is no "*NULL char*". There however is `NUL`. There also is a C "string"'s `null`/`0`-terminator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `fprintf()` to write binary data, of course it's going to interpret its formatting string as a string. That's what it does!

Use [`fwrite()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite), and open your file in binary mode with `"wb"`.

You can use `sizeof` to compute the size of the array, no need to hardcode the value:

```
FILE *picFile = fopen("pic.bmp", "wb");
if(picFile != NULL)
  fwrite(bmp1, sizeof bmp1, 1, picFile);
fclose(picFile);
```

This works because it's in the same scope as the array declaration of `bmp1`.

Comment: Specifically, in this case, `FILE *picFile = fopen("pic.bmp", "wb"); fwrite(bmp1, 1, sizeof(bmp1), picFile ); fclose(picFile);`

Comment: @Eregrith `fwrite()` takes the file at the end, buffer at the start.

Comment: @unwind interesting set of parameters for your fwrite() call, there. :-)

Comment: @PaulRoub wow indeed, sorry. I need more coffee (and I need to de-rust myself too sometimes... too much time without C and there it goes). I deleted my junk

Comment: btw, it seems it works the same here if we say fwrite(bmp1, sizeof bmp1, 1, picFile); as if we say  fwrite(bmp1, 1, sizeof bmp1, picFile);

Comment: @SuperHacker Yes, of course. That's because `1 * (sizeof bmp) == (sizeof bmp) * 1`. It's a matter of perspective (and, IMO, a rather silly API but that's what we have).

Comment: Note: 1) Using `fwrite(bmp1, sizeof bmp1, 1, picFile);` or `fwrite(bmp1, 1, sizeof bmp1, picFile);` normally results in different returns values: `1` or `sizeof bmp1`.  2) This is especially useful in times when size of an element * the number of elements exceeded `SIZE_MAX`.  This is also used in `calloc()`.  3) It matches `fread()` and there it is important to  read whole elements.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`fprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and its relatives are used to format some information and produce a **string** then write its characters<sup>1</sup> into a file or put it on screen or store it into a given array of characters.

Use function [`fwrite()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite) to write binary data; this function does not interpret the data you give it in any way and just writes the number of bytes you specify into the file.

Try this:

```
FILE *picFile = fopen("pic.bmp","w");
fwrite(bmp1, sizeof(bmp1), 1, picFile);
fclose(picFile);
```

*(your call to `fprintf()` was erroneous, anyway)*

---

<sup>1</sup>
The functions `sprintf()` and `snprintf()` (they put the generated string into a provided buffer of characters) copy the entire generated string onto their destination buffer, including the null terminating character.
The functions `fprintf()` (writes the string into a file) and `printf()` (puts the string on screen) **do not** put the null terminating character of the generated string into the output stream.

*(Thanks @chux for pointing out that the C strings include the null terminating character.)*

Comment: The input to `fprintf()` may take a _string_ like with `"%s"`, but `fprintf()` rarely outputs a _string_.  Instead it outputs characters and end-of-line codes translating `'\n'` to a system specific sequence.

Comment: @chux it depends of your interpretation of the word *"string"*. The documentation I linked to reads: *"Loads the data from the given locations, converts them to character string equivalents and writes the results to a variety of sinks."*

Comment: True about interpretation of the word "string".  With C code I use C's definition: "A _string_ is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." C11dr  §7.1.1.1 1

Comment: @chux Isn't the value produced by the `printf()` family of functions a string? (using the definition you quoted)

Comment: No, Example: `printf("%s%s", "Hello", "!")` takes 2 _strings_ `"Hello"` (which consists of 6 `char`: `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'\0'` and `"!"` which is 2 `char`.  It then prints out 6 `char`: `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, `'!'`.  The output does not include the terminating null characters.

Comment: @chux Now I see what you mean. I thought you are referring to the "contiguous" or "characters" part of the definition. I updated the answer with a footnote that explains the difference between `printf()/fprintf()` and `sprintf()/snprintf()` regarding the null terminating character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76088/discussion-between-chux-and-axiac).